# Replace a row in a R data.frame

Tags: r

I'm looking for an easy way to replace a row in a data.frame

```
dados <- data.frame(a = c("A", "B", "C"), b = c(1,2,3))
new_record <- data.frame(a = "G", b = 99)

# replace row
dados[2, ] <- new_record[1, ]
```

This doesn't work. What's the easiest way to make it work?

Comment: use `data.frame(..., stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: problem is that `dados$a` is a factor with (default) levels not containing "G"

Comment: You use rbind, as follows rbind(dados[1,],new_record[1,],dados[3,])

Comment: @CathG how do I turn an existing data.frame into a data.frame with stringsAsFactors = FALSE ?

Comment: if you cannot modify the way `dados` is created, you can either change the levels of `dados$a` prior to `dados[2, ] <- new_record[1, ]` (`dados$a <- factor(dados$a, levels=c(levels(dados$a), "G"))`) or put `dados$a` as character (`dados$a<-as.character(dados$a`), which will result in the same variable as if you had put `stringsAsFactors=F`, at least for `dados$a`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to / have to keep the column `a` as `factor`, you can adjust the factor levels first and then create the new data set:

```
levels(dados$a) <- union(levels(dados$a), new_record$a)
dados[2, ] <- new_record[1, ]
dados
#  a  b
#1 A  1
#2 G 99
#3 C  3
```

Answer (score 1):

[Andriy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3485304/andriy-tkachenko) is correct, use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when you create the data.frame. Otherwise, the generated factor levels won't match between the two data.frames and you'll see this warning:

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = 1L) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```